# Formik, React-Select & Multiple Variables

Tags: reactjs, next.js, formik, react-select

i'm entirely lost when it comes to figuring this out. I have a existing select that works with formik & react-select, but I can't get it to work as a multi. Here's what i have so far:

```
import Select from 'react-select';
import { useField } from 'formik';

export default function SelectField(props) {
  const [field, state, { setValue, setTouched }] = useField(props.field.name);

  const onChange = ({ value }) => {
    setValue(value);
  };

  return <Select {...props} onChange={onChange} onBlur={setTouched} />;
}
```

and

```
 <Field
     component={SelectField}
      name="campfeatures"
      options={selectObjects}
            />
```

How would I turn this into being capable of taking multi select? If I add isMulti to the Field, it "works" but it doesn't actually retain the multiple values.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The argument type for `onChange` changes when the `react-select` receives `isMulti` from a single object to a list of objects. When using isMulti you don't need to destruct; the first parameter is the value.

You also want to make the `react-select` a controlled component by managing its `value`.

```
export default function SelectField(props) {
  const [field, state, { setValue, setTouched }] = useField(props.field.name);
  
  // value is an array now
  const onChange = (value) => {
    setValue(value);
  };

 // use value to make this a  controlled component
 // now when the form receives a value for 'campfeatures' it will populate as expected
  return <Select {...props} value={state?.value} isMulti onChange={onChange} onBlur={setTouched} />;
}
```

The new value is an array of the selected options with label and value fields. If you want to store just the value you'll need to map it to a value and modify the `react-select` to handle that

Comment: Sorry for the delay in responding but thank you for this. This helps. Now I'm just stuck on how to apply the array to the router? This is what I have right now:

const handleSubmit = async values => {
    Router.push(
      {
        pathname: '/camps',
        query: { ...values, page: 1 },
      },
      undefined,
      { shallow: true }
    )
but if I do a search I get this:

http://localhost:3000/camps?region=all&camptype=State+Park&city=Twin+Mountain&campfeatures=&campfeatures=&page=1